# JSF h:column tag not evaluating rendered attribute

Tags: jsf

I've got a JSF data table that conditionally displays each item based on a Boolean property of the item, as follows:

```
<h:dataTable value='#{sessionBean.items}' var='item'>
    <h:column rendered='#{item.visible}'>
        <h:outputText value='#{item.description}'/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

My problem is that the `rendered` attribute does not seem to be referring to `visible` property in my item at all. I've put a tracing message in the getter for the property, and can confirm that the getter is not getting called at all. What **really** puzzles me though, is that the following works:

```
<h:dataTable value='#{sessionBean.items}' var='item'>
    <h:column rendered='true'>
        <h:outputText value='visible = #{item.visible}'/>
        <h:outputText value='#{item.description}'/>
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

That is, in this case all items are rendered, and the text "visible = true" or "visible = false" is successfully output for each. It is **only** in the column `rendered` attribute that the getter is not working.

Does anyone have any idea what might cause this behaviour, and what I should do to correct it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Table columns (read: `<td>` elements which are *all* in the *same* column, which thus applies on *all* rows) cannot be rendered on a per-row basis. That's not really a JSF restriction, but more a HTML restriction. Ask yourself, how should the HTML end up to look like? What should the browser do with all those missing `<td>` elements on a per-row basis? Right, it makes no sense at all :)

---

Just move the row-based rendering to the cell contents:

```
<h:column>
    <h:outputText value="#{item.description}" rendered="#{item.visible}"/>
</h:column>
```

Or make it a bean based rendering if you *actually* want to hide the whole column altogether:

```
<h:column rendered="#{sessionBean.visible}">
    <h:outputText value="#{item.description}"/>
</h:column>
```

Comment: I'm actually using an old codebase I was working with about a year ago. Oddly enough, it seemed to work ok back then... But I'll see if I can get the equivalent of what I need your way. Cheers!

Comment: Update: I've come up with an alternative approach based on your advice. I'm still utterly at a loss to explain how it worked before (you're absolutely right - it shouldn't have) other than perhaps things got changed in my absence and that particular little nugget of buglyness isn't my fault after all - I honestly can't recall. Thanks again for your help.

Comment: I've done some looking, and it seems I'm not the only one to have managed to get the desired behaviour using the h:column's `rendered` attribute - I found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2829457/conditionally-display-row-using-jsf-datatable/2958404#2958404) post earlier today. Now I'm **really** at a loss to explain why it worked before, but not now. That said, I'll still be changing to your approach - it does make sense.