# JSF datatable cell hide on condition of render

Tags: css, jsf, datatable

datatable:

```
<h:dataTable value="#{myController.items}" var="item">
<h:column>
                            <f:facet name="header">
                                <h:outputText value="test"/>
                            </f:facet>
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.number}" rendered="#{item.number eq LoginManager.number}"/>
                        </h:column>
```

Hi,
My bean always has data, but if rendered = false it still displays the row with empty cells. how can I hide the row & cells if the rendered = false only?

Regards.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem by adding the following in my css:

```
form.myListForm td:empty{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's easy to hide column in front end, but if you want to do what I think - You have got a list of some items but don't want to show certain items - then it would be much easier to implement that in your bean itself.